# Field-like Algebraic structure with infinite additive identities

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have a field-like structure with a set $F$ and two operations (addition and multiplication) and their respective inverses. It respects the following proprieties *similar* to a field:

- Associativity of $+$ and $\times$;
- Commutativity of $+$ and $\times$;
- Distributivity of $\times$ over $+$;
- A multiplicative identity $I$;
- Existence of additive and multiplicative inverses;

Notice how there is no mention of an additive identity. Furthermore, there exists a set $S$ containing "base" elements of $F$ (all elements of $F$ are derived from additions and multiplications of elements in $S$). For an element $A$ of $S$, $A+A^2$ doesn't make sense. You can only add elements that have the same power. Let's suppose there exists an additive identity $k$. This would entail the following:

$$ A+k = A \;\therefore\; A+(A^2-A^2) = A \;\therefore\; (A+A^2)-A^2 = A $$

Since we're adding elements with different powers, this equation suddenly doesn't make sense. To fix this, we can add the following axioms:

$$ a\neq b \implies k^a\neq k^b,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z $$
$$ A^n - A^n = k^n$$

Does an algebraic structure like this present any inconsistencies?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about inverses if you have no identity. If anything, you can talk about "division". $(a-b)$ could still make sense, but not just $-b$.

Comment: You lost me: if there's no additive "identity", how can there be additive inverses, or better said: what's their meaninng??

Comment: You cannot have additive inverses without an additive identity.  Also you can't have binary operations $+$ and $\times$ if $A+A^2$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in the concept of graded algebra. I think it would be helpful if you stated some motivation for this concept.

Comment: They have an inverse in the sense that $A^n-A^n = k^n$, for any $A$. So loosely speaking, $k^n$ is the additive inverse for any element of $F$ with order $n$. Can I not call this an identity?

Comment: Without an additive identity, additive inverses are undefined. Without additive inverses, subtraction is undefined. By definition, the symbol $A-B$ means $A + (-B)$, where $-B$ is the additive inverse of $B$.